# Migrating TransformerFactory Property from javax.xml.Transform to Jakarta in Spring 6 and Java 17

Tags: spring, jaxb, jakarta-migration

We're in the process of upgrading our application to Spring 6 and Java 17 from Java 11 and Spring 5. As part of this migration, we've come across a property set:

```
System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory","com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl");
```

Despite migrating our SOAP interfaces successfully, we're unsure about the necessity of this property.

How to migrate to Jakarta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the class `javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory` is still in the `java.xml` JDK17 module and still referenced in the jaxb-ri 4.x (under jakarta packages), I'd suggest not to change anything.

Same thing for `com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl` which is still under jdk17.

Comment: Yes, we also had the same thought, but we needed an expert review. Thank you for your review. We will keep it the same and till now we didn't find any error yet after migration

Comment: You're welcome, I've digged up in jaxb-ri 4.x source code for my answer